# Ubuntu 14.04 errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, error-handling

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.3.
I tried from software updater but first I get "Failed to download repository information" and I click on Ok and I get "Some software couldn't be checked for updates". So I tried to update from terminal with "sudo apt-get update" and I am getting these errors:

```
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.17.174 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Disable that repository. Chrome 32bit is no longer supported by Google. It's been almost two years: https://betanews.com/2015/11/30/google-killing-chrome-for-32-bit-linux/.

Comment: Did you run sudo update and sudo upgrade commands for 14 before upgrading to 16? If not I recommend trying that first.

Comment: Thank you! I did run them and then this problem occurred. I fixed it